# Select sum 3 table different record

Tags: sql, select, sum

I have 3 tables

1. tb_spp
2. tb_daycare
3. tb_antarjemput

Here is the contents of all three tables:

1. tb_spp

[image]

2. tb_daycare

[image]

3. tb_antarjemput

[image]

I want outpunya like this

[image]

And for the last output is limit 1 like this:

[image]

How to master?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Yes, that is true

Comment: please help me .

Answer (score -1):

You can refer my query for option 1.

```
select T1.kode, 
       T1.Nominal_spp, 
       T2.Nominal_antarjemput, 
       (IFNULL(T1.Nominal_spp, 0)*2 + IFNULL(T2.Nominal_antarjemput, 0)) as Total
from tb_spp as T1
left join tb_antarjemput as T2 on T1.kode = T2.kode
```

Comment: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: You use Sql or MySQL my friend?